# iOS - CoreBluetooth didDiscoverPeripheral called only once

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am actually making an app using Bluetooth Low Energy.

My app got 3 views so far, every one displaying some BLE informations.

When my Bluetooth protocole code was in the first view, there was no problem. But I decided to make a class and put my Bluetooth code into it, so I could make a global class for my 2 others views. I used:

```
self.bluetoothManager = [BluetoothManager getInstance];
```

BluetoothManager, being my global class.

And here is the problem:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

This method isnt looping anymore, it is called one time at the start only. I'm affraid the others services such as discoverCharacteristics or Notifications won't loop either.

Edit: This is how I create my class

```
+(BluetoothManager *)getInstance {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {
            instance= [[BluetoothManager alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

- (id) init {
    self.CentralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    self.activePeripheral = [CBPeripheral alloc];
    self.discoveredPeripherals = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.resultValue = [[NSString alloc] init];
    return self;
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        // Scan for devices
        [self.CentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];
        NSLog(@"Scanning started");
     }
}
```

Edit 2: So far, I did not post all the class methods to get a proper question but every methods from `CBCentralManager` delegate are implemented into my class.

So far I think my problem is about threads because the only difference is that my class isn't in the main queue anymore ? I did try a few things but I'm not confortable with threads, if anyone has a solution or idea to solve this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: We may need code of `BluetoothManager`, the creation part.

Comment: Thanks, added some informations about the creation.

Comment: Where do you initiate scanning for peripherals. What do you mean it isn't "looping"?  Have you specified the duplicate key to scanForPeripheralsWithServices?

Comment: I initiate scanning for peripherals on CentralManagerDidUpdateState. The code was working perfectly this way when the bluetooth code was inside the viewController file.   By not looping anymore, I mean my code only scans once, I got a NSLog inside to print any device found and it prints only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `didDiscoverPeripheral:...` callback was invoked successfully, this means that you did everything properly. When you call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:`, iOS starts scanning the surroundings in search for BLE devices. It will do so until you invoke `stopScan` explicitly or disable BT or kill your `CBCentralManager` instance. Some of peripheral devices will be found immediately, for some of them it will take more time. Each time when the device is discovered, `didDiscoverPeripheral:` callback is called. When this happens, it's your responsibility to decide whether you're interested in it, connect to it and discover its services.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! But I do remember `didDiscoverPeripheral` runs until I `stop scan`. I was finding again and again the same device (mine), which wasn't a bad thing since it was showing me the `didDiscoverPeripheral` method was looping. But now, it does not loop anymore, it just scans once.

Comment: I don't think you should rely on `didDiscoverPeripheral` "looping" or assume it's a good thing. It can happen indeed that this callback will be reported for several times per single peripheral (I'm not entirely sure why this happens, RSSI change maybe, who knows) but in my practice I always considered this being garbage. As soon as you find your peripheral, you can connect to it immediately and stop the scan. The only problem that is important is that your peripheral is not found at all, but I assume it's not the case here.

Comment: I was thinking about this but then I asked myself: what if I don't find right now my peripheral or if I forgot to plug it ? I'm actually making an array with peripheral discovered to show it into a tableview then show it to select the device. That's the only thing that bothers me, what if I need to scan once more for more peripheral ?

Comment: You don't need to explicitly scan for the peripherals more than once. If you don't see your device in a table, then you have to turn it on and it will soon appear there. If you want, you can of course call `scanForPeripherals:` for several times and keep a list of discovered ones. Just check the UUID of a newly discovered peripheral to see whether it's already found or not.

Comment: oh wow, you are so right, I don't know how I missed it. The first time I wrote my code, it was printing my peripheral like several times each seconds, I wrongly thought `scanForPeripherals:` was over-looping. Now it is printing only once but if I launch my scan then plug the device, it manages to find it, meaning I don't need it to loop since it acts as a listener I guess. Thank you very much for your help and your explanations which helped me to figure `scanForPeripherals:` acts more like a listener than a loop !

Comment: No problem, I was glad to help.